# Is it possible to scrape the tags under a div with xpath?

Tags: html, xpath, web-scraping, html-agility-pack

Consider the following:

```
<div class="name" data-starred-src="A Full Url"
data-non-starred-src="Some Other URL" data-reorderid="SomeID"
data-fbid="SomeID" id="SomeID" style="position: absolute;
margin-top: 0px; margin-left: 0px;">
```

This is a div element with a bunch of different attributes. The thing I want to scrape is the URL under "data-starred-src"

Is it possible to scrape this without taking the whole HTML?

Trying to do this using xpath and HtmlAgilityPack.

Comment: `//div[@class="name"]/@data-starred-src`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

XPath is capable of returning attribute, but HtmlAgilityPack appear to not support returning attribute value directly.You can try to select element that contains the target attribute first, and then call `GetAttributeValue()` on the element to get the actual attribute value, for example :

```
var raw = @"<div class='name' data-starred-src='A Full Url'
data-non-starred-src='Some Other URL' data-reorderid='SomeID'
data-fbid='SomeID' id='SomeID' style='position: absolute;
margin-top: 0px; margin-left: 0px;'></div>";

var doc = new HtmlDocument();
doc.LoadHtml(raw);
var div = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//div[@data-starred-src]");
var url = div.GetAttributeValue("data-starred-src", "");
Console.WriteLine(url);
```

**<kbd>[`dotnetfiddle demo`](https://dotnetfiddle.net/4RVD4e)</kbd>**

**output :**

```
A Full Url
```

Comment: Tried this and worked fine with the OuterHtml. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This will work for you.

```
response = """"<div class="name" data-starred-src="A Full Url"
 data-non-starred-src="Some Other URL" data-reorderid="SomeID"
 data-fbid="SomeID" id="SomeID" style="position: absolute; 
 margin-top: 0px; margin-left: 0px;">"""
response_sel = Selector(response)
url = response_sel.xpath('//div[@data-starred-src]/@@data-starred-src')
```